# Is it possible to use the org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin to bundle native dlls into a war file?

Tags: java, maven, package, bundle, native

I have a group of java projects built with maven.

Now one of them depends on a native DLL, which in turns depends on several others, all of which I build as well. The final product of the build is a war file. I need these dlls to be inside that war file.

I know that one way to do it is include these dlls as resources of the respective java project. Doing so means I have to copy these dlls to the resources directory of the respective java project before that project is built.

But I am trying to explore another way and not sure whether it is just me that is doing it wrong or is it simply not possible. I am talking about the `attach-artifact` goal of the `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin`.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

The root level pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
  <name>VCat-build</name>
  <version>1.0.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>VCat-build</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>../../../../DriverProxy</module>
    <module>../../../VCat</module>
    <!-- More modules follow -->
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The native DLL's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shunra.localDriverProxy</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <artifactId>local-driver-proxy</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Local Driver Proxy</name>
  <properties>
    <msbuild.exe>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</msbuild.exe>
    <msbuild.configuration>StratusRelease</msbuild.configuration>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <executable>${msbuild.exe}</executable>
          <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>clean-with-msbuild</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>
                <argument>/t:Clean</argument>
                <argument>/p:Configuration=${msbuild.configuration}</argument>
                <argument>LocalDriverProxy.sln</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>build-with-msbuild</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>
                <argument>/t:Build</argument>
                <argument>/p:Configuration=${msbuild.configuration}</argument>
                <argument>LocalDriverProxy.sln</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-local-driver-proxy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                <artifact>
                  <file>${basedir}/../Distribution/DataStruct.dll</file>
                  <classifier>DataStruct</classifier>
                  <type>dll</type>
                </artifact>
                <artifact>
                  <file>${basedir}/../Distribution/GraphSetup.dll</file>
                  <classifier>GraphSetup</classifier>
                  <type>dll</type>
                </artifact>
                <!-- more artifacts follow -->
              </artifacts>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The Java project's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
  <artifactId>vcat</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Quite a few dependencies follow -->
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>target/exploded</webappDirectory>
          <archive>
            <!-- <manifest>
               <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           </manifest> -->
          </archive>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-war</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Running `mvn package` succeeds, the war file is created, but it does not contain any of the native DLLs. These DLLs are built just fine, but they are never copied anywhere.

I ran `mvn -X`. Here are the lines, which I think are relevant:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: o:\java\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre
.
.
.
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact (attach-local-driver-proxy)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <artifacts>
    <artifact>
      <file>C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy/../Distribution/DataStruct.dll</file>
      <classifier>DataStruct</classifier>
      <type>dll</type>
    </artifact>
    <artifact>
      <file>C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy/../Distribution/GraphSetup.dll</file>
      <classifier>GraphSetup</classifier>
      <type>dll</type>
    </artifact>
    .
    .
    .
  </artifacts>
  <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
  <mavenSession>${session}</mavenSession>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <runOnlyAtExecutionRoot default-value="false">${buildhelper.runOnlyAtExecutionRoot}</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
  <skipAttach default-value="false">${buildhelper.skipAttach}</skipAttach>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] com.shunra.localDriverProxy:local-driver-proxy:pom:0.0.1
.
.
.
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact (attach-local-driver-proxy) @ local-driver-proxy ---
[DEBUG] org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:jar:1.7:
.
.
.
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:jar:1.7
.
.
.
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3326b249]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) file = C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy\..\Distribution\DataStruct.dll
[DEBUG]   (s) classifier = DataStruct
[DEBUG]   (s) type = dll
[DEBUG]   (s) file = C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy\..\Distribution\GraphSetup.dll
[DEBUG]   (s) classifier = GraphSetup
[DEBUG]   (s) type = dll
.
.
.
[DEBUG]   (f) artifacts = [org.codehaus.mojo.buildhelper.Artifact@7e79b177, ...]
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@37567e6c
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.shunra.localDriverProxy:local-driver-proxy:0.0.1 @ C:\dev\shunra\DriverProxy\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) runOnlyAtExecutionRoot = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipAttach = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

I am not that familiar with maven, so I might have omitted important parts from the log. The complete  log is here - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fhZCmGxB (I removed the logs of the builds of several other java projects, they all look the same, but take huge amount of space)

So my question is this - can I use the `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin` to do what I need - bundle native DLLs into the war?

**EDIT**

I have tried the approach suggested by SpaceTrucker, no errors are produced, but the resulting war remains the same - no DLL is packaged. The maven log contains the following entries:

```
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] com.shunra:vcat:war:0.0.1
.
.
.
[DEBUG]    com.shunra.localDriverProxy:local-driver-proxy:dll:DataStruct:0.0.1:compile
.
.
.
[INFO] Exploding webapp...
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources to C:\dev\shunra\Application\VCat\target\exploded
[INFO] Assembling webapp vcat in C:\dev\shunra\Application\VCat\target\exploded
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
.
.
.
[DEBUG] Processing: local-driver-proxy-0.0.1.dll
[DEBUG] Skipping artifact of type dll for WEB-INF/lib
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.0.1:war (default-war) @ vcat ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.0.1:war from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.0.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@3326b249]
.
.
.
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Exploding webapp...
[INFO] Copy webapp webResources to C:\dev\shunra\Application\VCat\target\exploded
[INFO] Assembling webapp vcat in C:\dev\shunra\Application\VCat\target\exploded
[DEBUG] Processing: spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
.
.
.
[DEBUG] Processing: local-driver-proxy-0.0.1.dll
[DEBUG] Skipping artifact of type dll for WEB-INF/lib
[INFO] Generating war C:\dev\shunra\Application\VCat\target\vcat-0.0.1.war
```

The log mentions `local-driver-proxy-0.0.1.dll`, but this files does not exist!

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9940273/116509

Comment: That question is not relevant. I know I can pack native dlls and I even mention in the question body that I could place the files in the resources and that would make them packed into war. My specific interest is in the `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin` and that question never mentions it.

Comment: OK, up to you. Good luck doing anything with the DLL once it's in your war.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your pom is that there is no dependency declared from the Java Project that builds the war to the project containing the native dll. You should be fine when declaring this dependency.

EDIT:
add this to the `dependencies` section of your war files pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.shunra.localDriverProxy</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <artifactId>local-driver-proxy</artifactId>
  <classifier>DataStruct</classifier>
  <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion. A am very new to maven, so if you could spare a few sample lines that would save me some googling.

Comment: Are you sure this is all I have to do? Because I have added this dependency to the war generating pom.xml and got this: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project vcat: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.shunra:vcat:war:0.0.1: Could not find artifact com.shunra.localDriverProxy:local-driver-proxy:dll:0.0.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @mark I forgot the `classifier` tag in the xml snippet. I'm not quite sure if this will work if you are depending on the `DataStruct` and the `GraphSetup` at the same time. If it doesn't then you would have to create a separate pom for each dll.

Comment: Well, it does not work - see the EDIT. And creating a separate pom for each dll is kind of a nuisance. I need another approach. I guess I will just have to package them as resources or something.

Comment: @mark You have to make sure that the maven assembly plugin also includes the dll. Please have a look at the documentation of it - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/ - This might have been asked already on SO.

Comment: The task becomes too complicated. I'll just include them as resources. +1 for the effort. Thank you.